# 'Object of type TextChannel is not JSON serializable' when trying to create a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so if a channel is deleted, it will be remade after an hour. But when I use this code:

```py
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel): 
            guild = channel.guild                   
      await guild.create_text_channel(channel)
```

It returns: `Object of type TextChannel is not JSON serializable`

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the channels name](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel) with `str`:

```
await guild.create_text_channel(str(channel))
```

Comment: may i ask you a semi-related question? i cant post another question for 90 minutes.

Comment: Do you know how to make the channel go back to where it was? Like if i deleted a channel called 'memes' it would remake itself, and then go back to the same postion it was at. Right now, it just goes to the top.

Comment: I've actually never used Discord. I tried searching their docs for "position" but that seems to relate to the role of users. Sorry I couldn't help further.

Comment: Thank's for trying. Should I just make another question?